# Prove or disprove that $GL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ is a P.I.D.

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, ring-theory

Prove or disprove that $GL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ is a P.I.D.

So, ideals of $GL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ are precisely of the form $GL_2(I)$ where $I \triangleleft \mathbb{Z}$, and since $\mathbb{Z}$ is a P.I.D. we have $I = n\mathbb{Z}$ for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$

It seems like it would be awfully hard for there to be one matrix that generates all the invertible matrices with coefficients in $n\mathbb{Z}$, which is what an ideal of $GL_2(\mathbb{Z})$  looks like, but I'm having a hard time showing this. Can somebody help me out?

Comment: Principal ideal domains are usually required to be commutative rings, right?

Comment: What is the ring structure on $GL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ that you are considering?

Comment: Yeah, I think so, even integrals are supposed to be commutative. Thanks, totally forgot this obvious thing.

Comment: Principal ideal domains are usually to be rings, right?

Comment: Matrix addition and multiplication

Comment: This is not stable by addition.

Comment: @MathematicalMushroom We do not have matrix addition in $GL_2$

Comment: Well i am confused then, arn't ideals of $GL_2(R)$ of the form $GL_2(I)$ where $I \triangleleft R$?

Comment: It depends what you call an ideal. But if you're thinking about the classical notion of ideals of rings, then $GL_2(R)$ is just not a ring.

Comment: Why is it not a ring under matrix addition and multiplication?

Comment: If $GL_2$ is to be an abelian group under matrix addition, then it has to contain the zero matrix.  But the zero matrix is not invertible so isn't in $GL_2$.

Comment: Ah, okay, thanks. I meant to say $M_2(\mathbb{Z})$ haha, oops.

Comment: Well, PIDs are still usually required to be commutative.

Comment: @MathematicalMushroom In any case you should at least edit your post.

Comment: $M_2(\mathbb{Z})$ isn't a domain, so not PID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As everyone says in the comments: $\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$ is not a ring --- it's a nonabelian group under multiplication. PIDs are commutative rings, so these are very different objects. Unless you have defined some addition/multiplication on the set $\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$ to make it a commutative ring, the question makes no sense. Even entrywise operations would not make $\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$ into a ring.

Either way: it is an abuse of terminology. To most mathematicians, the symbol
$\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$ refers not just to the *set* of invertible matrices, but the resulting *group* under multiplication. To separate this set from its group operation is somewhat offensive to most people, as you can see from the comments.

---

But I think this is the most charitable interpretation of your question: "is every ideal of $M_2(\mathbb{Z})$ principal?"

*This* question makes sense and the answer is "yes". Every ideal of $M_n(\mathbb{Z})$ is of the form $M_n(I)$ for some ideal $I$ of $\mathbb{Z}$, and all such $I$ are principal.

Comment: Is it simple to understand how the generator for $M_n(I)$ relates to $(a)=I$?

Comment: Yep --- notice a ring $R$ embeds in $M_n(R)$ diagonally (scalar multiples of the identity), say $a\mapsto aI$ where $I$ is the identity matrix. Now if $J = (a)$ is a principal ideal of $R$, then $M_n(J) = (aI)$ is the principal ideal generated by $aI$.